# How can i force cache reseting with in Nuxt 3 usign SWR rendering Mode?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3, node.js-fs, nitro

I'm working with Nuxt 3, I have the "routeRoules" property in my "nuxt.config.ts" file and I was learning about the different rendering modes, I want to use SWR mode but I need to have the possibility to reset the cache manually, for example with an endpoint that I will call with a button in an admin UI, I couldn't find any information on this, but digging inside the .nuxt folder I could see that the cache is saved to a folder using .json files, The folder path I found is: "././nuxt/cache/" so I thought of a workaround that deletes that folder with all the files inside, this works for me but I don't think it's the best solution:

the endpoint that does this:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

function removeFolderRecursive(folderPath) {
  if (fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
    fs.readdirSync(folderPath).forEach((file) => {
      const currentPath = `${folderPath}/${file}`;

      if (fs.lstatSync(currentPath).isDirectory()) {
        // Recursively remove subfolders.
        removeFolderRecursive(currentPath);
      } else {
        // Remove files.
        fs.unlinkSync(currentPath);
        console.log(`Deleted file: ${currentPath}`);
      }
    });

    // Finally, remove the folder itself.
    fs.rmdirSync(folderPath);
    console.log(`Deleted folder: ${folderPath}`);
  }
}

export default defineEventHandler(async function (event) {
  const folderPath = path.resolve("./.nuxt/cache/nitro/routes/_");

  try {
    removeFolderRecursive(folderPath);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error deleting folder:", err);
  }

  return "ok";
});
```

Can anyone give me a better way to do this? Or guide me to better understand what I can do to solve my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75849646/can-you-invalidate-swr-static-routes-depending-on-user-actions-using-hybrid-rend